# Import SQL Server Script Text into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, vba

I have a lot of views and stored procedures I periodically need to review, and in order to do so, I paste the TSQL from SQL Server into an Excel spreadsheet where I can create formulas to analyse it.

Is there a way (using VBA?) to import the actual script from a defined view or stored procedure into a cell in Excel?

So just to confirm, I want to return the script, and not the results of executing the script.

Many Thanks

Comment: How are you reviewing stored procedures in Excel?  Maybe you should look into an SVN solution which has a DIFF viewer.  Something like http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SQL point of view you can get the view text using this query:

```
SELECT [definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE [name] = 'ViewName'
AND [type] = 'V'
```

for procs change the WHERE to:

```
WHERE [name] = 'Procname'
AND [Type] = 'P'
```

**Edit:** here is a quick VBA function to return this data, just replace the connection details:

```
Public Function GetObject(ByVal nm As String, ByVal Tp As String) As String

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim retval As String

    With objMyConn
      .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[MyID];Password=[MyPass];Data Source=[ServerName];" & _
      "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
      "Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=[DBName]"
      .Open
    End With

    strSQL = "SELECT [definition] " & _
    "FROM sys.sql_modules m " & _
    "INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id " & _
    "WHERE [name] = '" & nm & _
    "' AND [Type] = '" & Tp & "'"


    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

    Do While Not objMyRecordset.EOF

        retval = objMyRecordset.Fields("description").Value

        objMyRecordset.MoveNext

    Loop

    Set GetObject = retval

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this great response. I have imported this VBA and tweaked the connection string to point to my SQL Server which I believe are 100% correct.  I also had to remove the last "SET" before Set Get Object.  I still manage to get "#Value" when using this function in a cell.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd set a breakpoint at the `objMyRecordset.Open` line and check the value of `strSQL`, run this value manually against the DB to make sure it returns the right info.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find the exec sp_helptext useful for this as it will split the output into seperate rows instead of one column, which might make it easier to view in excel.

```
exec sp_helptext "YourView/SP"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "code" (the T-SQL definition) for your stored procedures from SQL Server by inspecting the `sys.procedures` and `sys.sql_modules` catalog views:

```
SELECT
    [pr].[name] ,
    [pr].[object_id] ,
    [pr].[type_desc] ,
    [pr].[create_date] ,
    [pr].[modify_date] ,
    [m].[definition] ,
    [m].[uses_ansi_nulls] ,
    [m].[uses_quoted_identifier] ,
    [m].[is_schema_bound] 
FROM sys.[procedures] pr
INNER JOIN sys.[sql_modules] m ON [pr].[object_id] = [m].[object_id]
WHERE pr.Name = 'whatever_stored_proc_name_you_want_to_analyze'
```

Same goes for views:

```
SELECT
    v.[name] ,
    v.[object_id] ,
    v.[type_desc] ,
    v.[create_date] ,
    v.[modify_date] ,
    [m].[definition] ,
    [m].[uses_ansi_nulls] ,
    [m].[uses_quoted_identifier] ,
    [m].[is_schema_bound] 
FROM sys.views v
INNER JOIN sys.[sql_modules] m ON v.[object_id] = [m].[object_id]
WHERE v.Name = 'whatever_view_you_want_to_analyze'
```